# Rao-Blackwellizing: Is there any difference conditional on different sufficient statistics

Tags: rao-blackwell

1. Suppose I have two different sufficient statistics $a_1$ and $a_2$ while $a_1$ summarizes information more efficient than $a_2$. 
   For example, if the sample space is $\left\{y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6\right\}$, then for $a_2$, the new partition for sample space may be $\left\{r_1,r_2,r_3\right\}$ $r_1$ summarizes information from $y_1$ and $y_2$, $r_2$ summarizes information from $y_3$ and $y_4$, and so on. Then for $a_2$, the original sample space is divided into three pieces. If using $a_1$, the new sample space may be $\left\{u_1,u_2\right\}$, just two partitions. Since for $a_1$, it has fewer partitions, thus achieving data reduction more efficiently.
2. $x$ is an unbiased estimator for $\theta$. When using Rao-Blackwellizing, I get two different unbiased estimators if conditional $x$ on different sufficient statistics: $\mathbb{E}(x|a_1)$ and $\mathbb{E}(x|a_2)$.

Can I say that $V(\mathbb{E}(x|a_1)) < V(\mathbb{E}(x|a_2))$ ? If so, how to prove?

Comment: What does "much more sufficient" mean?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to be "more sufficient". A statistic is either sufficient or it isn't. Can you clarify your intent? ... How does your question arise?

Comment: @dsaxton I mean that a1 can summarize information more effectively. For example, if the sample space is {y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6}, then for a2, the new partition for sample space may be {r1,r2,r3}  r1 summarizes information y1 and y2, r2 summarizes information from y3 and y4, and so on. Then for a2, the original sample space is divided into three pieces. If using a1, the new sample space may be {u1,u2}. Since for a1, it has fewer partitions, thus acheiving data reduction more efficient. This is what I what to express. Thanks !

Comment: @Nicole please edit to fix your question -- it should not be necessary to read all the comments to see what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

If you think about where the result comes from the answer is a bit more clear.  Rao-Blackwellization is based on the fact that

\begin{align}
\text{Var}(T) &= \text{Var}[\text{E}(T \mid S)] + \text{E} [ \text{Var}(T \mid S)] .
\end{align}

So if you have two sufficient statistics $S_1$ and $S_2$ then $\text{Var}[\text{E}(T \mid S_1)] < \text{Var}[\text{E}(T \mid S_2)]$ if and only if $\text{E} [ \text{Var}(T \mid S_1)] > \text{E} [ \text{Var}(T \mid S_2)]$.  This means that, on average, conditioning on $S_1$ causes a smaller decrease in the variance of $T$, or that $S_1$ provides less information about $T$.  This is in line with the idea of $S_1$ generating a more "coarse" partitioning of the sample space than $S_2$, which is to say it achieves greater data reduction.

In general it *does* matter what sufficient statistic we're conditioning on.  Consider for example that the whole sample is itself a trivial sufficient statistic, but in this case conditioning doesn't actually accomplish anything.  What we want are sufficient statistics that summarize the information in the sample, ideally using a single number.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It seems that there's no difference between E(Var(T|S1)) and E(Var(T|S1)).   E(V(T|S1)) = E[E(T^{2}|S1)-(E(T|S1))^{2}] = E(T^{2})-\Theta   Assume my estimator is unbiased

Comment: @Nicole I made some edits to try to relate things to the idea of "summarizing" the information in the sample.  Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Rao Blackwellizing while conditioning on a sufficient statistic gives you a better estimator given that you initial estiamtor is unbiased.
However if you condition of a complete sufficient statistic then you will reach the best unbiased estimator.
There is no general rule that I know of, that specifies which sufficient statistic will give smaller variance, you will need to check the variance of the estimators

Comment: Please endorse if you find the answer usefull